# Print array which was filled in other funciton

Tags: c

I trying reverse my string and print that result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *string, char *revstr)
{   
    int length, i, j;

    length = strlen(string);

    for (i=length, j=0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        revstr[j] = string[i];
    }
}

int void()
{   
    char string[] = "reverse!";
    int length = strlen(string);
    char revstr[length];
    int i;

    reverse(string, revstr);

    printf("%s", revstr); //nothing
    for (i=0; i<=strlen(string); i++) {
        printf("%c", revstr[i]); //It's work
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int void()` I think it should be `int main()`

Comment: @row248 If this `char revstr[length];` compiles for you then add tag `c99`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From C definition a string is *a contiguous sequence of characters
        terminated by and including the first null character*. You should not reverse the trailing null terminator of the string.

Change:

```
for (i=length, j=0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
```

to this

```
for (i = length - 1, j=0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
```

and manually add the trailing null terminator at the end of your `reverse` function:

```
revstr[length] = '\0';
```

You should also reserve enough room for the null terminator:

Change:

```
char revstr[length];
```

to this:

```
char revstr[length + 1];
```

Comment: don't forget about `int void()` :)